# Is there any Query Library in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

If I have a table of some properties (for example 5) .

```
Property1   Property2  Property3 Property4 Property5
ex11        ex12        ex13     ex14       ex15
ex21        ex22        ex23     ex24       ex25
ex31        ex32        ex33     ex34       ex35
```

All these properties are  of different types. Is there any good way or good library so that if we have any example of any property, then to get all other properties of example in efficient time.

For example:

```
Property2Of(ex31);
Property4of(ex31);
```

The above calls should return their respective properties and only property1 is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Boost.MultiIndex. It should be quite efficient.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html